# htaccess continues to prompt for password after login

Tags: .htaccess

This has ALWAYS worked before so I'm not sure why it isn't working now.

**Scenario**

I have work done in a folder that I would like a different user to view. When they visit it their username/password combo works but whenever they navigate to a different page they are prompted again with the sign in prompt. However when they use my account it works as expected.

**Question**

What's going on here and how can I get around it? I've made a number of attempts to get around this with no success.

## Notes

- My user is a linux user on the machine
- Their user is an htaccess user with a (SHA) htpasswd record
- This didn't start happening until recently (I'm not aware of any server updates)
- I've tried this from multiple browsers, multiple OS's, multiple IP's

## .htaccess

```
AuthUserFile /var/www/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Required"
Require user jackson david
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from All
# jackson home
Allow from xx.xx.xx.219
Satisfy Any
```

## Server Info

```
$ apache -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Jul 15 2016 15:34:04

$ lsb_release -a
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

Comment: Is there more than 1 .htaccess file or are there also restrictions placed in your main httpd.conf (or any files included therein)?

Comment: @HBruijn There is a "master" .htaccess three directories above that is the same but with a single `Require user jackson` - I set it up this way so my user has access to everything but then I would attach other users to specific directories so they were "sandboxed" to those specific directories. I want to reiterate that this worked for years until recently (maybe within the last year or so)

Comment: @HBruijn after further investigation, I disabled (renamed) the master `.htaccess` and that stopped the process of have to enter the other user's password over and over. As soon as I re-enable the master `.htaccess` I'm back to square one. So the culprit has been identified but I'm still dumbfounded as to why this only just started - maybe it's modern browsers ?

Comment: It's not old browsers, I just tried this on a really old version of safari. Maybe it's a network level thing, idk.

Comment: the master list is applied AFTER the child list [according to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6665136/332578) so I added the second user to the master `.htaccess` and that worked. Not to figure out a workaround..

Comment: Just to draw your attention to... you are on Apache 2.4, but are using the "deprecated" Apache 2.2 auth directives (`Order`, `Allow`, `Deny`, ...) - you should consider replacing these with the equivalent Apache 2.4+ directives and at the same time ensure you are not mixing old/new directives throughout your system - since this can result in unexpected conflicts.

Comment: per @MrWhite's comment, check out the [guide to upgrading apache directives from 2.2 to 2.4](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basic authentication requires the browser to send your credentials with *each* HTTP request and the server will prompt you for those when you try to access a password protected area without a valid username/password.

Basic Authentication is also [limited in scope](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7617#section-2.2)  and when you go outside of the initial scope your browser stops sending your known credentials with each request.

For example, given an authenticated request to:

```
  http://example.com/folder/docs/index.html
```

requests to the URIs below could use the known credentials:

```
  http://example.com/folder/docs/
  http://example.com/folder/docs/test.doc
  http://example.com/folder/docs/?page=1
  http://example.com/folder/docs/archive/1999/old.doc
```

while the URIs

```
  http://example.com/folder/other/
  http://example.com/folder/
  http://example.com/
  https://example.com/folder/docs/
      ^
```

would be considered to be outside the authentication scope. If one or more of those location are also password protected (for instance with a different .htaccess file) the server will need to prompt your browser to supply credentials AGAIN.

When the domain is the same and "realm" (the value of `AuthName` i.e.  `"Password Required"`) is the same for both area's on your web server the browser will first try the known credentials. If the realm is different, the browser won't use the known credentials but will show you a login prompt.

With nested authentication and different "realm" values, but  identical valid username/password combinations (see below) you will get slightly counter intuitive behavior that the order in which you visit the URL's matters

```
        URL                        Authname            Valid Users
   http://example.com/folder       "Private"           jackson
   http://example.com/folder/docs  "Password Required" jackson david
```

First going to `http://example.com/folder/docs` will store your password but due to different realm you would be prompted for a password when you go outside the original context to `http://example.com/folder`.

When you first visit `http://example.com/folder` your credentials are stored and will be sent automatically when you go to `http://example.com/folder/docs` as that is in the same context. Because the server won't need to prompt you for credentials your browser won't even notice that it is a different realm now.

Comment: Oh wow so this "buggy" behavior was simply because the `Authname` matched in both files.